# How to setup the background color on a radial plot?

Tags: r, plot, colors, plotrix

I need to draw a target. I have selected the `plotrix` library. My current result and code are below:
[image]

```
library(plotrix)

pmax  <- 30 

rho   <- seq(pmax, 7.5, by=-2.5) 
phi   <- seq(0, 360, length=10) 

radial.plot(rho, phi, rp.type = "s", point.symbols=19, 
           radial.labels=seq(pmax, 10, by=-5), start=pi/2, clockwise=TRUE, labels=LETTERS[1:4], main="Test Radial Plot")
```

**Question.**
Is it possible to fill all circles of the target with different colors in `plotrix` library? Or should I use alternative library?

[image]